# Missing Vaadin dependencies from org.vaadin.artur

Tags: docker, maven, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am experimenting with the Vaadin Flow framework for creating a web application. I have configured and downloaded the test application as a Maven project, as described here: https://start.vaadin.com/app/

However, this project is unable to download two required dependencies from Maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
    <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The required repo is already in my POM:

```
<repository>
    <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
    <url>http://vaadin.com/nexus/content/repositories/vaadin-addons</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

When I download the JARs manually and add them to my local .m2 repo, the project builds fine, so there is a workaround. But I still would like to understand why these dependencies are not retrieved from Maven. Also, this is a problem for the docker build, which fails, because it doesn't access my local Maven repo, of course.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The vaadin part is in several ways wrong...first it uses http instead of https furthermore the url is wrong (https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons) and to access that you have to have a license of vaadin ...as far as I know..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, @khmarbaise. I should have mentioned that I have already tried both URLs. Also, using HTTPS doesn't make a difference. The Maven build still fails to download the required depedencies. It might be the case that you need a license, but if so, it doesn't make much to require a license for a demo project, IMHO.

Comment: No license is needed for download and both of the packages are also using the Apache 2 license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was due to our internal repository setup. We're using Nexus, which also acts as a Maven Central proxy. Since these two dependencies are not listed on Central, I had to add the JARs manually to Nexus and also configure the Nexus repo in the POM.xml. The build then worked ok.

Comment: This is wrong. You should configure that remote repository as a proxy and add to the public group you are using...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got the repository from but if you go to https://start.vaadin.com and download an app, the pom.xml contains

```
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

which should be the correct repository URL

Comment: The URL mentioned in my post is the one I got from Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.vaadin.artur/a-vaadin-helper/1.7.1   But even using `https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons` the dependency still fails to download.